# ms build dynamic resource naming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, csproj

I want to add some files to embedded resourses at compile time with special naming. For this I wrote in `.csproj`

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="..\Bin\$(Configuration)\*.*">
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

But it always set `<LogicalName>` to default.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct. Where is your project located? I think you don't need `..\`

Comment: yes, I'm sure. It's special "bin" folder with dll's from another project.

Comment: Does it work if you specify only one file without wildcards: `..\Bin\$(Configuration)\SomeFile.ext`?

Comment: Yes. with many files it works too. But I found solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. This renaming works:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Frameworks Include="..\Bin\$(Configuration)\Frameworks\*.*" />
      <Steps Include="..\Bin\$(Configuration)\Steps\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(Frameworks)">
        <LogicalName>Frameworks.%(Filename)%(Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(Steps)">
        <LogicalName>Steps.%(Filename)%(Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="EmbeddedResource - @(EmbeddedResource)" />
  </Target>
```